# Misunderstanding on phases (progressive mechanical waves)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Say we have a rope and we start to move it up and down, creating a wave.

The equation of the source, $\text{S}$, would be$$
Y_{\text{S}}(t)=a \sin{\left(\omega t\, + \,\varphi_{\text{S}}\right)}
\,,$$ and of a point, $\text{M}$, would be$$
Y_{\text{M}}(t) = a \sin{\left(\omega t \, + \, \varphi_{\text{M}}\right)}
\,.$$If I were to say that the source, $\text{S}$ and the point, $\text{M}$, are in opposition of phase that would come to say that,$$
Y_{\text{S}}(t)=Y_{\text{M}}\left(t\, + \, \frac{T}{2}\right)
\,,$$which goes down to say$$
φ_{\text{S}} \, - \, φ_{\text{M}} ~=~ \pi \left(2k+1\right)
\,,$$and at the same time it's also correct to do this$$
Y_{\text{S}}(t)=Y_{\text{M}}\left(t \, - \, \frac{T}{2}\right)
\,,$$leading to$$
φ_{\text{S}} \, - \, φ_{\text{M}}~=~π\left(2k \, - \, 1\right)
\,.$$My question is which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherently both are correct. You just get confused by the fact that you used the variable $k$ twice.

Both solutions tell you that the phase difference is an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: No I know that, but in answering the question "Find all points vibrating in opposition of phase at t = t0", φs-φm initially = 2π(x/λ) but if I were to suppose that it's equal to π(2k+1) it wouldn't be the same as supposing it's π(2k-1) when solving for k (first solve for x and then 0 < x < l with l rope's length)

Comment: It would give the same overall solutions. The physically relevant quantity is nog $k$, but the position $x$. The solutions ($k$) for both methods are just shifted over $2\pi$ with respect to eachother.

Comment: Of course I also meant a shift over 1 in $k$ or just a shift of $2\pi$ in phase. Not a mixture of them.